# How to Setup kerberos in a load balanced message broker environment?

Tags: load-balancing, kerberos, ibm-integration-bus, netscaler

We have `IIB 10.0.0.12` running on `Windows Server 2012 R2`. We are looking to setup `Kerberos` -Token based authentication for SOAP services that are exposed to internal/external consumers.

We have around 4 System test servers running on a Same domain. The test servers are not load balanced; can we create a Single User account (Say "IIBTestPrincipal") in Active Directory and map multiple SPN's to this user account and setup the test environments like below.

```
setspn -A HTTP/server3.somedomain.co.uk@SOMEDOMAIN.CO.UK IIBADPrincipal 

setspn -A HTTP/server5.somedomain.co.uk@SOMEDOMAIN.CO.UK IIBADPrincipal
```

Can somebody please advice/ guide on process for setting the same in load balanced environment.?

We have 4 broker servers load balanced via `Netscalar`. Can the load balancer perform a kerberos passthrough and broker perform all the kerberos authentication work ? If so should we be creating a SPN on Load balancer Host name and map all the prod servers as alias to that SPN ?

Couldn't find much info from Info center,Any thoughts on the above are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Netscaler supports Kerberos impersonation and Kerberos contrained delegation. I'm not that familiar with Kerberos, take a look in their documentation
https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX222453